# Pure Javascript, Cannot assign variables to an array

Tags: javascript

I am still learning JS (not jquery). So in learning, I am starting with a simple game. I found a problem. I cannot get these arrays to work, as they are producing a `NaN`.

```
var clickMultiplier = 1.11;
var idleMultiplier = 1.15;
var idleBuffsCost = [];
idleBuffsCost[0] = 100;
var clickBuffsCost = [];
clickBuffsCost[0] = 100;
var trainerBuffsCost = [];
trainerBuffsCost[0] = 1250;

for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  var j = i - 1;
  idleBuffsCost[i] += idleBuffsCost[j] * idleMultiplier;
  clickBuffsCost[i] = clickBuffsCost[i] + clickBuffsCost[j] * clickMultiplier;
  trainerBuffsCost[i] += trainerBuffsCost[j] * 1.25;
}
console.log(clickBuffsCost[0]); // works = 100
console.log(clickBuffsCost[1]); // does not work NaN
```

What am I doing wrong?
Also, I am used to doing arrays (like the above) as

```
... idleBuffsCost[i-1]
```

However, that does not seem to be working.
What do you think? Am I not seeing the forest for the trees (I normally program in php/mysql/pascal/qb64(and other derivations) and a few more languages - just adding JS to the list hahaha)

ps the different assignments are because I was trying different logic operations.

thanks to a few people here - I made a simple mistake. the loop was trying to assign a value to an index that was not assigned yet. Here is the fix  - I removed the += and left just =

```
idleBuffsCost[i] = idleBuffsCost[j] * idleMultiplier;
clickBuffsCost[i] = clickBuffsCost[j] * clickMultiplier;
trainerBuffsCost[i] = trainerBuffsCost[j] * 1.25;
```

special thanks to: @certainPeformance, @Wais Kamal and @David I wish I could green check them all. But they were helpful none-the-less, Thanks guys!

Comment: I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: idleMultiplier is not defined`

Comment: What are the values of idleMultiplier and clickMultiplier

Comment: `+=` adds or concatenates with the *existing variable* on the left, but every `[i]` index is `undefined` at the start of a loop

Comment: How do you want this to work? Are the elements in the array besides index 0 meant to start out as 0? Then you have to set them to 0 initially.

Comment: I'm guessing you want all values to start as 0. So use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill before you set the values in index 0. Then set those, then do your loop.

Comment: forgot to put that in the OP:  var clickMultiplier = 1.11;
var idleMultiplier = 1.15;

Comment: you can edit your own question @JakeStone

Comment: why the down votes - question is not listed anywhere else? sometimes it takes a second pair of eyes to help solve a problem. Even if it is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where you've gone wrong:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  var j = i - 1;
  idleBuffsCost[i] += idleBuffsCost[j] * idleMultiplier;
  clickBuffsCost[i] = clickBuffsCost[i] + (clickBuffsCost[j] * clickMultiplier);
  trainerBuffsCost[i] += trainerBuffsCost[j] * 1.25;
}
```

First of all, define `i` before using it. Defining variables is good programming practice.

```
clickBuffsCost[i] = clickBuffsCost[i] + (clickBuffsCost[j] * clickMultiplier);
```

In the first iteration of your loop, `i` has the value 1, while `j` has the value 0. You are setting the second element of `clickBuffsCost` as `clickBuffsCost[i] + (clickBuffsCost[j] * clickMultiplier)`. `clickBuffsCost[i]` (which is equal to `clickBuffsCost[1]` in this case) is undefined, which is why you are getting NaN when calling `console.log(clickBuffsCost[0])`.

Comment: Hi.. I only posted the offending piece, i,j,k is declared earlier. And thank you very much for your clarification. When I was debugging this, for some reason I cold not see that LOL.  Many thanks! Cheers

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a little mistake in your code. Search this line of code.

```
clickBuffsCost[i] = clickBuffsCost[i] + (clickBuffsCost[j] * clickMultiplier);
```

change to:

```
clickBuffsCost[i] = clickBuffsCost[j] + (clickBuffsCost[j] * clickMultiplier); // notice the difference after the = part
```

Since `i` will start at 1, `clickBuffsCost[1]` is undefined because `clickBuffsCost` only consists of one item at the beginning.

Comment: I had to look at that twice to see what you mean.. Let me verify that.

Answer (score -4):

You need to initialise your array lengths. For example, if you know you have 20 elements in an array, you should initialise an array as follows:

`const testArr = new Array(20);`.

Alternatively, if you don't know the length of your array, instead of indexing the ith element of the array and assigning it a value, you could use the array `push(..)` function. This method means you do not have to initialise an array with a length.

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Not necessary to set the length upfront.

Comment: helpful tip: JS array expand dynamically, only need to use var arry = [];